# Needed some explanation to understand the get property code in this unity game tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just want to know if the get property code in this script(on the end) is a shorthand code, which says, if the shootCooldown is less than or equal to 0 then return true?

if it is, then is this another way of writing an if condition?For me, the code seems to be returning a float value and not a boolean.

the whole code is posted below:

```
    public class WeaponScript : MonoBehaviour 
  {
  public Transform shotPrefab;
  public float shootingRate = 0.25f;
  private float shootCooldown;

  void Start()
  {
    shootCooldown = 0f;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (shootCooldown > 0)
    {
      shootCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
  }

  public void Attack(bool isEnemy)
  {
    if (CanAttack)
    {
      shootCooldown = shootingRate;

      // Create a new shot
      var shotTransform = Instantiate(shotPrefab) as Transform;

      // Assign position
      shotTransform.position = transform.position;

      // The is enemy property
      ShotScript shot = shotTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<ShotScript>();
      if (shot != null)
      {
        shot.isEnemyShot = isEnemy;
      }

      // Make the weapon shot always towards it
      MoveScript move = shotTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<MoveScript>();
      if (move != null)
      {
        move.direction = this.transform.right; // towards in 2D space is the right of the sprite
      }
    }
  }

  public bool CanAttack
  {
    get
    {
      return shootCooldown <= 0f;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is exactly that, what part of it don't you understand? you seem to understand it just fine.

Comment: It seems you already have the understanding of that code.

Comment: Definetely. You can use "shootCooldown <= 0f" wherever you see "CanAttack" and nothing changes. But instead of shorthand notation it makes code reusability and maintainability easier and makes the code more parametric. Suppose that the coındition changes from "x <= 0" to "x <= 100". You should update many code blocks on a large application. But with thi you just change one line and system updates itself for every usage of CanAttack.

Comment: The beauty of taking this approach is that you don't have to store a separate bool. Imagine if you have a property for `CanAttack` and you had to update it every time the `shootCooldown` changes (i.e. if it goes above 0 you set it it true). That would be much more prone to bugs, but this way you evaluate the current value as and when you need it

Comment: when i saw this code, i expected to see something like if shootCooldown is less than or equal to 0 return true; but here it just says return shootCooldown <= 0f; and I cannot understand this part, for me it seems it will return a float vaue

Comment: It returns a `bool` because `shootCooldown <= 0f` is a condition - it will either evaluate to `true` or `false` depending on the value of `shootCooldown` (which is, as you have said, a `float`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code of the property does not return the value of

```
shootCooldown
```

But the result of the expression

```
shootCooldown <= 0f;
```

which is resolved to boolean.

It is equivalent to writing

```
if (shootCooldown <= 0f)
{
       return true;
}
else 
{
       return false;
}
```